# How Can I use glClipPlane more than 6 times in OPENGL?

Tags: opengl

I have a Sphere . I would like to clip some planes like below picture. I need more than 10 clipping plane but maximum glClipPlane limit is 6. How can I solve this problem.

[image]

My Sample Code below;

```
double[] eqn = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.72};
        double[] eqn2 = { -1.0, 0.0, -0.5, 0.80 };
        double[] eqnK = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.40 };
        /*  */
        Gl.glClipPlane(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0, eqn);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
        /*  */
        Gl.glClipPlane(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE1, eqn2);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE1);

        Gl.glClipPlane(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE2, eqnK);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE2);          



        //// draw sphere           
        Gl.glColor3f(0.5f, .5f, 0.5f);
        Glu.gluSphere(quadratic, 0.8f, 50, 50);
        Glu.gluDeleteQuadric(quadratic);
        Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE0);

        Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE1);
        Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE2);
```

Comment: Instead of clipping all the holes, why not simply make and/or calculate that sphere'ish thingy to already have all the holes.

Comment: If you're using shaders, you can pass as many as would fit to fragment shader's uniforms, check point location against planes and `discard` fragments that doesn't pass at least one plane.

Comment: @keltar: Technically clip planes work not at the fragment but on the primitive setup level. You can do it in the fragment shader of course. But given recent enough hardware you can implement cliping in the vertex setup shader stages.

Comment: @datenwolf well i know that it have no good place in fragment shader, it is just a first thing came to mind. It also appears to be possible in geometry shader, although tricky. As for vertex - never tried it, could you hint an example? (especially since `glClipPlane` is removed in new GL profiles)

Comment: check OpenCSG, maybe you need it, instead of clipping.

Comment: @keltar: No, you have it all wrong. In the vertex shader you are not supposed to do clipping - you can, however, compute the user clip plane distances at this stage. It depends on your version of GLSL, whether you use a single arbitrary clip coordinate or output distances from each clip plane (GLSL 130).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need a sample code. I may compute the clip plane distances, then what can  I do. Any small hint will be appreciate.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman er, i never said it is possible on vertex stage - this is exactly why i asked for hint how it could be done. How clip distance could be used is welcome too - maybe it fits this? (never used it). So what exactly have i got wrong, could you tell?

Comment: @Libyssa you haven't told if you could use shaders (preferably GLSL). What version is available? What language is that?

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell it.sorry. I'm using Tao Framework with C#. But I have no idea about  using GLSL.

Comment: @keltar: Sorry, I kind of combined both you and datenwolf's comments in my head... datenwolf is most likely referring to `gl_ClipDistance` in GL3. This lets you compute the distance to each clip plane per-vertex instead of the old system where each vertex had a `gl_ClipVertex` position associated with it and the actual distance test against each plane was done in the primitive assembly stage. The great thing about that is you can select the set of clip planes to test against in the vertex shader since primitive assembly does not need to know the actual plane equations, just distance.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider multi-pass rendering and the stencil buffer.

Say you need 10 user clip-planes and you are limited to 6, you can setup the first 6, render the scene into the stencil buffer and then do a second pass with the remaining 4 clip planes. You would then use the stencil buffer to reject parts of the screen that were clipped on the prior pass. So this way you get the effect of 10 user clip planes when the implementation only supports 6.

```c
// In this example you want 10 clip planes but you can only do 6 per-pass,
//   so you need 1 extra pass.
const int num_extra_clip_passes = 1;

glClear       (GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

// Disable color and depth writes for the extra clipping passes
glDepthMask   (GL_FALSE);
glColorMask   (GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);

// Increment the stencil buffer value by 1 for every part of the sphere
//   that is not clipped.
glStencilOp   (GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR);
glStencilFunc (GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xFFFF);

// Setup Clip Planes: 0 through 5
// Draw Sphere

// Reject any part of the sphere that did not pass _all_ of the clipping passes
glStencilFunc (GL_EQUAL, num_extra_clip_passes, 0xFFFF);

// Re-enable color and depth writes
glDepthMask   (GL_TRUE);
glColorMask   (GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);

// Setup Leftover Clip Planes
// DrawSphere
```

It is not perfect, it is quite fill-rate intensive and limits you to a total of 1536 clip planes (given an 8-bit stencil buffer), but it will get the job done without resorting to features present only in GLSL 130+ (namely `gl_ClipDistance []`).

Comment: I think I couldn't succeed it. First part of the code till drawing sphere works. but second sphere and clip planes don't work i think..

Comment: @Libyssa: Do you have a stencil buffer in your pixel format? Most drawing applications do not need it, so they don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can just reuse  "`Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CLIP_PLANE1);`" because you was disabled it later ...